# how to import module that in bundle?

Tags: systemjs

I have bundle index.js containing named modules

```
System.register('app/bootstrap', ['./router'], function() {
   return {
    setters: [...],
    execute: function() {...}
});
System.register('app/router', function() {
   return {
    setters: [...],
    execute: function() {...}
});
```

I try to import the app/bootstrap module in index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
   ...
   <script src="/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  System.config({
        baseURL: "/",
        defaultJSExtensions: 'js',
        transpiler: false,
        packages: {
            'app': {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
    System.import('app/bootstrap').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</body>
</html>
```

I see that the module is in the variable System.defined but systemjs makes a request for the URL /app/bootstrap.js. Maybe a bug in SystemJs?